# how to display the modified file path in git log

Tags: github, git-log

I have a GitHub repository with many different folders containing many sub folders and files. After making a commit to a particular file it would be really helpful if the git log shows the modified file name along with the file path inside the repository.

```
for example like : repo/<path-to-the-modified-file>
```

Does any know how to display the modified file path in the `git log`

Answer (score 0):

For showing the list of files changed in the last commit, just use:

```
 git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD
```

For previous commits, use HEAD~1 HEAD~2 etc...